# How can I get my ubuntu boot manager back after Windows 7 install?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot-manager

I had Ubuntu in one partition and Vista in another.

The Ubuntu boot manager would come up and ask me if I wanted Ubuntu or Vista.

After installing Windows 7 over Vista, upon booting there is no sign of Ubuntu.

Is there a way I can log into Ubuntu some how in its partition and set up the Ubuntu boot manager again so that when I boot the machine it asks me if I want to use Windows 7 or Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HowToGeek [explains how to reinstall the Grub Bootloader](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/reinstall-ubuntu-grub-bootloader-after-windows-wipes-it-out/) after a Windows install wipes it out.

There's also [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) if those steps aren't working for you.